# Error on Reporting Server but not in SSRS or SSMS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, dataset, ssrs-2016, ssms-2014

I have a report that errors out on the report server (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2016), but runs fine in SSRS (Visual Studios 2015), and SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio 2014) when copying and pasting the dataset query into SQL.

The error I get on the reporting server is:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
 Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
 For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Just to add a little more information, I have reports in the same folder on the reporting server, using the same data source that run fine.

I'm stuck.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this question somehow related to or maybe the same as your previous question? Please ask a question only once.

Comment: It is different, one of the two issues were resolved since my last question.  This is the one issue that remains.

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52726177/6777839) is a different problem and it is resolved, would please post the solution. For the current problem, please add more details.